# Prevent storing of post data in elmah allxml field by default

Tags: elmah

Is there any way to turn the storing of post data in the allxml database field off by default? In some instances (specific webforms pages or specific controllers / actions) I might want to turn it *on explicitly* but *on by default* feels like it would be very easy to accidently capture sensitive data in your logs (passwords, cc nums...). It's a similar argument to disabling viewstate by default IMO.